# Why is React fetch ignoring the JSON data I'm getting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am teaching myself how to "fetch" data within React. However, although I am able to grab the JSON data from a local file, it somehow disappears when I try to place it into the component's state.

I am using the following tutorial. The precise code I'm copying is the second image at this link:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/#react-how-fetch-data

For example, the below code, in the log, returns the correct data:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { cardData: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
   fetch(cardDataJsonLocation)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.cardData));
}
```

When I look at the console in my browser, the correct data is being logged - an array with 2 objects in it:

```
﻿
[{…}, {…}] 0: {name: "dom", id: 1} 1: {name: "dave", id: 2}
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0)
```

However, when I change the above code to actually place the above array data in my component's state:

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch(cardDataJsonLocation)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ cardData: data.cardData }))
  .then(console.log(this.state));
}
```

When I log the state, there's no change from the original state I set in the constructor.

In this case, it logs an empty array. If I set the state (in the constructor) to, say, [1,2,3] or null, then that value comes down instead.

Am I missing a step in the fetch process? It's as if it skips the step where I try to setState after fetch. Thanks.

Comment: `.then(console.log(this.state));` is missing a `() =>`

Comment: common setState missunderstanding - async nature - read docs - there is a special warning about that

Comment: `this.setState({ cardData: data.cardData }, () => { console.log(this.state); })`

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed and as described in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), `setState()` is an async method.

If you need to access the state immediately after calling setState, then put your code in a callback and pass this callback as the second parameter of setState, like in:

```
this.setState({ cardData: data.cardData }, () => { console.log(this.state); })
```

Comment: Yes that's it - thanks. I wouldn't have even thought of searching through the documentation to see if setState was asynchronous.